# Git Update Local Branch with remote Master

Tags: git, gitlab

I see two possibilities of doing this:

1. Do a replace of the local branch with the changes from remote master
2. Follow the work flow that I get using Gitlab by creating a merge request and merge the changes from master branch into the branch that I wish to update to the latest from master

What are the advantages and disadvantages of both these approaches? I'm leaning more towards the first approach. What do you guys say?

Comment: I'm a bit confused by your question - do you mean that you want to overwrite what you have locally with the contents of the remote master? Or just that you want to get the changes from master into your current branch? Maybe it's a [rebase](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) that you're looking for?

Comment: Yes, changes from master into my current branch is what I want!

Answer (score 95, accepted):

The simple answer - there are plenty of more complicated ones - is to just do a merge, so:

```
git checkout master
git pull
git checkout <your-branch>
git merge master
```

(This is effectively the same as you describe in option 2)

Depending on your settings, you might not need all of those steps (but doing them all won't hurt) - I'd recommend reading up on each of the commands to find the precise workflow that fits you best.

This will merge the changes from master into your branch and probably create a new commit, with a comment making it clear that it's a merge.

The alternative, and slightly more advanced option would be to `rebase`, instead of `merge`, which will effectively rewind time to the point at which your branch diverged from master, then pull in the changes on master, bringing your branch in-line with master, but without your commits, and finally apply your commits at the end. The advantage of this is that it keeps the history more simple - you just get a straight line of changes, with the changes from your branch right at the end, rather than two separate branches that join at the point of the merge.

To do that, you'd do:

```
git checkout <your-branch>
git rebase master
```

I'd recommend reading the docs on rebase, because there are lots of cases where it gets difficult, and if you're new to git, definitely go for merge, but come back to rebase when you're more confident - it's a very powerful feature, and more like what I think you're describing in your option 1.

Answer (score 8):

If you `remote` is set to the default `origin`, (you can check it by using `git remote -v`), you could just do:

```
git merge origin master
```

Comment: I always forget with this - do you need to fetch/pull *first*? If so, it'd be good to add to the answer to remind other users...

Comment: @coatesap you can simply use git pull in order not to forget make fetch first.
git fetch + git merge = git pull. But do not forget to stage (or commit) all the local changes first or you will lose them after merge.

Answer (score 5):

When you in your current branch `git merge master`

Comment: Note that this will need the local master to be up-to-date with the remote master to work correctly. The commands in DaveyDaveDave's will make sure that is the case before running `git merge master`.

Answer (score 2):

You can rebase also:

```
git rebase origin/master
```

Comment: This is assuming that one has run `git fetch` first, right? Otherwise `origin/master` might not contain the latest changes from the remote master (`origin master`).

Comment: @TimSkovJacobsen Yes